# Custom validation causing other validations to fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Title pretty much explains the problem.

Here were my validations for my model:

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  has_many   :users, through: :goals
  has_many   :goals, dependent: :destroy

  validates :school_id, presence: true
  validates :date, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :school_id }
  validates :attendance, numericality: { only_integer: true,
                                         greater_than: 0 },
                         presence: true, if: :finished?
  validates :lesson_plan_week_number, numericality: { only_integer: true,
                                                      greater_than: 0 },
                                      presence: true, if: :finished?
end
```

All of my model tests (aside from the ones dealing with the custom validation) pass with the above code

Then I added `validate :motion_presence` and the following private method:

```
def motion_validation
  if debate?
    errors.add(:motion, "must be present if a debate was held")
  else
    errors.add(:motion, "cannot be present if a debate was held")
  end
end
```

and now the tests that once passed are failing. What's happening?

Here's the relevant code in the model if I'm organizing it incorrectly

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  has_many   :users, through: :goals
  has_many   :goals, dependent: :destroy

  validates :school_id, presence: true
  validates :date, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :school_id }
  validates :attendance, numericality: { only_integer: true,
                                         greater_than: 0 },
                         presence: true, if: :finished?
  validates :lesson_plan_week_number, numericality: { only_integer: true,
                                                      greater_than: 0 },
                                      presence: true, if: :finished?
  validate  :motion_presence

  private

    # Validates the motion depending on debate?
    def motion_presence
      if debate?
        errors.add(:motion, "must be present if a debate was held")
      else
        errors.add(:motion, "cannot be present if a debate was held")
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: that i guess is because in any case whether `debate` returns true or false, it is adding errors to the motion so it will never be successful resulting in not saving the lesson object as errors are already added for motion field. i think you need to add a case where it should just return without adding any errors.

Comment: Also, where the heck does `debate` come from? Did you mean `self.debate`?

Comment: @Athar, that seems to be the issue. I'll fix the validation. If you post your response as an aser I'll mark it as the correct answer

Comment: @MarsAtomic It is self.debate?, is it better practice to prefi it with self. even though it's not necessary?

Comment: `self` is more clear. I guess it's down to whether you want code to be more accessible to others vs. less verbose.

Answer (score 0):

```
def motion_presence
  if debate?
    errors.add(:motion, "must be present if a debate was held")
  else
    errors.add(:motion, "cannot be present if a debate was held")
  end
end
```

This will always fail because you added to `errors` in either case.

If you wanted to fail it for multiple conditions, then try doing it in `elsif`. `else` means `EVERYTHING ELSE` and its failing always.

Do it like this:

```
def motion_presence
  if debate?
    errors.add(:motion, "must be present if a debate was held")
  elsif some_condition
    errors.add(:motion, "cannot be present if a debate was held")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because in any case whether `debate?` returns true or false, it is adding errors to the motion so it will never be successful which results in not saving the lesson object as errors are already added for motion field.

**I think you need to add a case where it should just return without adding any errors. Besides just add errors for specific cases**

Comment: Actually, he does not need an explicit return without adding any error. He can just add errors for specific cases.

Comment: Thanks @KMRakibulIslam. That was actually for his understanding. but thanks your point is good.